# Display Online Users

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to find out how do you display a online users? Once they are logged in I want it to be shown on my members page, for now I got how many users I got. I also want a timeout if a user close the browser or logout it will not show any online users, this is the code for the total members...

```
<? 

if ($_GET[user] != "") { 

$check_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$lowerusername'"); 

if (mysql_num_rows($check_query) != "0") {

} else {

header("Location: /usernotfound.php");



} 

}

?>
<?
$username = $_SESSION['membersusername'];
$check_query3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
while ($display = mysql_fetch_array($check_query3)) {
    $bio = $display['bio'];


}
?>
<?

if ($_GET[user] != ""){

$check_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$lowerusername'");

  while ($display = mysql_fetch_array($check_query)) {

$twitter = $display['twitter'];
    $facebook = $display['facebook'];
$tinychat = $display['tinychat'];
$vaughnlive= $display['vaughnlive'];
$uploadbanner = $display['uploadbanner'];
$uploadbg= $display['uploadbg'];
$backgroundcolor = $display['backgroundcolor'];
$bgp = $display['bgp'];
$bgr = $display['bgr'];
$bga = $display['bga'];
$btc = $display['btc'];
$image = $display['image'];
            $status1 = $display['status']; 

    $djname2 = ":: $djname2 Profile";

$djname3 = "$djname3";

    $djname = "<strong>Name:</strong> $name";

        $age = "<strong>DOB:</strong> $age1";

        $email = "<strong>E-Mail:</strong> <a href='mailto:$email1'>$email1</a>";

        $year = date('d/m/Y');

        $totalage = $year-$age1;



}}

?>

<?

if ($_GET[user] != ""){

$check_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE username='$lowerusername'");

  while ($display = mysql_fetch_array($check_query)) {

$twitter = $display['twitter'];
    $facebook = $display['facebook'];
$tinychat = $display['tinychat'];
$vaughnlive= $display['vaughnlive'];
$uploadbanner = $display['uploadbanner'];
$uploadbg= $display['uploadbg'];
$backgroundcolor = $display['backgroundcolor'];
$bgp = $display['bgp'];
$bgr = $display['bgr'];
$bga = $display['bga'];
$btc = $display['btc']; 
$username = $display['username'];
$image = $display['image'];

 }}
?>
<? $check_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE username='$_SESSION[membersusername]'");

  while ($display = mysql_fetch_array($check_query)) {

$image1 = $display['image'];

        if ($image1 == "") { 



    $image1 = "profile/nophoto.gif";

    } else {

        $image1 = "profile/$username/$image1";



        }} 

    ?>
     <?

$check_query_all = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE hiddenauth='no' AND auth='yes' ORDER BY id DESC");
while ($display = mysql_fetch_array($check_query_all)) {
$allmembers = $display['name'];
$allusername = $display['username'];
$allbio = $display['bio'];
$allage = $display['age'];
// get more stuff above if u need
$check_query_all2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE username='$allusername'");
while ($display = mysql_fetch_array($check_query_all2)) {
$allimage = $display['image'];
$alllocation = $display['location'];

// Check Album Photo's
    $check_amount = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE hiddenauth='no' AND auth='yes'");
    $num_djs_total = mysql_num_rows($check_amount);

// CHECK IF IMAGE OR NOT
if ($allimage == "") {
$allcheckedimage = "nopic.gif"; }

// CHECK IF IMAGE OR NOT
if ($allimage != "") {
$allcheckedimage = "$allusername/$allimage"; } 


// CHECK IF location OR NOT
if ($alllocation == "") {
$allcheckedlocation = "No Idea"; }

// CHECK IF location OR NOT
if ($alllocation != "") {
$allcheckedlocation = "$alllocation"; } 



// CHECK IF mini bio OR NOT
if ($allbio == "") {
$allcheckedbio = "Something about your show."; }

// CHECK IF mini bio OR NOT
if ($allbio != "") {
$allcheckedbio = "$allbio"; } 


$listalldjs .= "<table class='inlineTable' width='452' border='0'>
  <tr>
    <td width='20%'><img src='$domain/profile/$allcheckedimage'  width='180' height='173'/></td>
    <td width='83%'><b>Username:</b> $allusername<br /><b>Location:</b> $allcheckedlocation<br /><b>Show Description:</b><br>$allcheckedbio<div align='right'><a href='$domain/$allusername'/>View Channel</a>
</div> </td>
  </tr> 
</table>";
}}


?>
```

This is the login code...

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<? include "includes/dbconfig.php"; ?>
<? include "includes/loggedin_config.php"; ?>
<?
$lowerusername = strtolower($_POST[username]);
// MEMBERS LOGIN CHECK IF USER EXISTS :D

if ($_GET[action] == "login") {

$check_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$lowerusername' AND password='$_POST[password]' AND auth='yes'");

         if (mysql_num_rows($check_query) != "1") {

        $error = "Incorrect details! or You have not authorized your account!";

        } else {



$_SESSION[ipaddress] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$_SESSION[membersusername] = $lowerusername;

 header('Location: main.php');
 }

 }

?>
```

Can anyone help me make a online only script not total members? If so what do I need to add to MySQL table?

Thanks

Comment: Note: Your login-SQL-query is not SQL-injection-safe since it looks like you are using input-data in your query without filtering: `AND password='$_POST[password]'`.

Comment: Every user-defined variable that you want to use in a database-query should be filtered, which means removing html and php-tags with `strip_tags()`to prevent XSS-Attacks and masking quotes with `addslashes()` to prevent SQL-Injections:
`$username = strip_tags(addslashes($username));`
There are better methods, but this basically secures your queries.

Answer (score 2):

Note

> mysql_* functions are depreciated. Use **PDO** or **MySQLi**

Make sure the time zone on MySQL server an PHP server is **UTC**.

Add a `seen` column to your MySQL users Table.

When a logged in user visits any page on your web site, update the "seen" row of current user to SQL function `NOW()` :

```
$username = $_SESSION['membersusername'];
if(isset($username)){
 mysql_query("UPDATE users SET seen=NOW() WHERE username='$username'");
}
```

If a user just stays in your page, send a **AJAX** request to a page where the **seen** row is updated.

On the page where you want to display online users, loop through the users, check if the "seen" row is less than current time - 20 seconds.

If it's less than 20 seconds, that user is offline. Else the user's online.
Example

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT seen FROM users");
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
 $seen=$rows['seen'];
 if($seen < date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime('-20 seconds', time()))){
  echo "User Is offline";
 }else{
  echo "User is online";
 }
}
```

You can set this **20** seconds to more or less time.

Comment: @MBell86 Did you do the things I mentioned in the post.

Comment: Gone to that chat thing but your no there.?

Comment: I'm about to do it now.

Comment: @MBell86 Chat requires atleast 10 reputation

Comment: Ahh, any other way to chat to you?

Comment: Ok signed up to open.subinsb.com am online :)

Comment: Added code  but getting this when I add the user is online... http://prntscr.com/2s3syv

Answer (score 1):

You need a cron.

Every 10 seconds,check if the user is logged in?

step1.Enter a flag value "yes" in a table field when a user logs in.

step 2.Every 10 seconds check whether the user is logged in or not : you can fire a query when user logs out or when user closes the tab and update the exact same field with a flag  "no" .

Make sure you use cookies properly if you are using any.